# Best way to convert nested data into class object

Tags: c#, linq

I have data stored in db in the following form (example):

[image]

In column called "Identify" we have sections separated by dots.

The aim is to convert this data into an object like this:

```
class Example
{
    public string Identify { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Example> NextLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Which allow me to use library and achieve something like:

[image]

The first column is a section which is build like a chapter in book. Every chapter can contains multiple items and each item contains description and code. As you can see, all the chapters are stored in one db cell, which tell us how many "levels" should be built.

I tried a recursive method, but it was also weak. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

about question how it should look in code:

```
 Example firstResult = new Example();
        firstResult.Identity = "Car";
        firstResult.NextLevel = new List<Example>()
        {
             new Example { Identity = "trucks", Code = "des", Description = "more description"},
             new Example { Identity = "Another truck", Code = "xyz", Description = "really nice truck" },
             new Example { Identity = "18wheels", NextLevel = new List<Example>()
                        {
                            new Example{ Description = "and another description", Code = "saw"}
                        }
             },
        };
```

there is a limit how many subsections can be - 3

Comment: Please add any required data/code directly into your question instead of posting screenshots. Thank you.

Comment: Please show the attempt you made, so we have some idea of how you're querying the database and creating objects. Also, what would the end result look like in code (not the table, but the object)? I'm mostly interested in how you want to populate `NextLevel`, as the other fields are mapped `1:1` easily. Does `Car` have a `NextLevel` that contains `Trucks`, which has a `NextLevel` that contains `18wheels`? And what do you do with an `Example` like `Home.Flats`, where there is no data for the root node (`Home`)?

Comment: Data from Db are getting by DAPPER and mapped on simple C# class where:

example for first row
int permissionId = "1";
string Details = "some details";
string Identify = "Car";

Comment: If you want to be really lazy I would create three columns for identify, then split that string on the period, and the length of that array would tell you which column to put it into.

Comment: Please explain how the three columns of `section name` relates to `Identity` and make your `firstResult` example match your picture example, because I don't see where `trucks` contains any levels in `firstResult`.